# jquery issue. after reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#data').load('data.php');
}, 10000);

$(".banit").click(function() {
var namer= $(this).val();
alert(namer);

});

</script>
```

Data from data.php is loaded into div with id data every 10 sec
this data has a buttons (looped and echoed in php) with class banit. and button banit has value something.. this value something has to be alerted.

now once the page is opened this button works and alerts fine! but once the data is reloaded it stops working!
please help!

Answer (score 3):

When you call `$('#data').load('data.php');`, you destroy all child elements of `#data`, including the button and its click handler.

You have to either rebind the click event after loading the new content or use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(".banit").live('click', function() {
    var namer= $(this).val();
    alert(namer);
});
```

Event handlers bound with `live` will work for all current *and* future DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

Like piquadrat says, you have to rebind the handler each time, but I'd rather use the "delegate" method like paul irish says here : http://www.slideshare.net/paul.irish/perfcompression (slide 34 to 38).